# get directory listing for bundling

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have a directory of files that I would like to be individually minified. However, BundleConfig.cs does not seem to let me use `Server.MapPath`, so I'm unsure of how I can write a loop to iterate over the individual files in a directory and bundle/minify them individually.

I'd like to do something like this in BundleConfig.cs:

```
string[] dir = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/stuff/css"));
foreach (....) {
    bundles.Add();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation, there is a method [IncludeDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj646483.aspx) which should do what you want.

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/jQueryUI/themes/baseAll")
.IncludeDirectory("~/Content/themes/base", "*.css"));
```

There's a good tutorial on bundling on the asp.net site:

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification

To iterate them individually, this should work:

```
string virtualDirectory = "~/Styles";
string directory = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(virtualDirectory);
foreach (string fileName in Directory.GetFiles(directory))
{
    bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~style/minified/" + fileName).Include(virtualDirectory + "/" + fileName));
}
```

You will need to add a using for System.IO.

Comment: i would like to have individual files though, not combine them.

Comment: Added some code that iterates over the files, but this doesn't have the additional benefit of reducing the number of web requests, which can have a big impact on performance, especially for mobile clients.